# remove args from ana array in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, discord.js

i wanna remove an argument that i prevously added to an array with a command, the code i made:

```
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
const multipleArgs = args.slice(1).join(" ");

const banWordAdded = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#42f59b')
        .setTitle("Ban word added:")
        .setFooter(multipleArgs)

const banWordRemoved = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#42f59b')
        .setTitle("Ban word removed:")
        .setFooter(multipleArgs)

        if (banWords.some(word => message.content.toLowerCase().includes(word))) {
            message.delete()
            message.channel.send("Don't say that!");

    } else if (command === 'banword') {

        if (!message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.channel.send("You can't use this command")
        if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send("Choose either add or remove")
        
        if (args[0] == 'add')

        banWords.push(multipleArgs)
        message.channel.send(banWordAdded)
        console.log("Array updated");

    } else if (args[0] == 'remove') {

        delete banWords(multipleArgs)
        message.channel.send(banWordRemoved)
        console.log("Array updated")
```

It works just fine when adding a ban word, but when i wanna remove it the bot deletes the command message for containing the banword instead of removing it from the banWords array, like i do q!banword remove example and the message gets deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`delete` is used to remove `Object properties`, therefore it will not work on arrays. You can use `Array.prototype.splice()`or `Array filter()` method to accomplish this.

**Method 1 .splice()**

```js
const indexOfWord = banWords.indexOf(multipleArgs); // finding the element in the arr
if (indexOfWord == -1) return message.channel.send('word not found'); // if word isn't already in the array return
banWords.splice(indexOfWord, 1); // removing the word
// first parameter is the index of the element to remove, second one is the number of elements to remove.
```

**Method 2 .filter()**

```js
const filteredArr = banWords.filter(x => x != multipleArgs); // filteredArr won't contain the words provided
```

I believe splice would be ideal for you as it doesn't create a new array, instead it modifies the existing array. hope this helped

Comment: @TomTheItalianBBQ np :D